# How to remove the live text from an AVPlayer

Tags: swift, avplayer

We are noticing that there is a live text button in our video player (AVPlayer).  It comes up behind some of our custom controls, so we either want to disable the feature in this video or move it.

Can't seem to find a flag for this, or access to the control to move it.  We have implemented our own control set and disabled the native controls.

Image:  Notice the OCR button on the far right:

[image: Notice the OCR button on the far right]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can disable it by using a special flag `allowsVideoFrameAnalysis` [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/3986071-allowsvideoframeanalysis)

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player

if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
    playerViewController.allowsVideoFrameAnalysis = false
}
```